# USB Headset: 2x circumaural with mic

Tags: usb, audio, headphones, microphones, headset

Okay, so I originally posted this almost two weeks ago and it's gotten exactly zero attention.  (got me a tumbleweed badge too)  Surely someone knows of something, so I'll edit a bit and see if I can be more clear:

---

I'm looking for something that:

1. Runs entirely on USB, not USB power with separate analog signal

   - An analog 'set with USB adapter would be okay, if the PC only sees the one USB plug
2. Has closed-back circumaural cans to block out ambient noise
3. Has a microphone attached to one of the cans
4. Can rotate those cans enough to hold one to my ear for a few seconds while the other stays mostly out of sight.

   - I've used some ear-only 'phones that rotate 180deg - that's really nice - and I've also tried some gaming 'sets that only go 90deg.  The 90's seem to be hit-or-miss whether they actually go far enough.
   - I'll also put it all the way on for other tasks, so I do need both ears.

I've found some gaming headsets that almost fit the bill, but it seems to be difficult to find some that both rotate far enough and can be purely USB as far as the PC is concerned.

Is there something that satisfies *all 4* requirements?